# How can I manipulate a string a T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

| business_id | open_day | open_time | close_day | close_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FRIDAY | 08:00 | FRIDAY | 12:00 |
| 1 | FRIDAY | 13:00 | FRIDAY | 17:00 |
| 1 | MONDAY | 08:00 | MONDAY | 17:00 |
| 2 | SATURDAY | 08:00 | SATURDAY | 16:00 |
| 2 | SUNDAY | 08:00 | SUNDAY | 16:00 |
| 3 | MONDAY | 08:00 | MONDAY | 16:00 |

I have a task to create and format opening hours for a business, I'm required to group these by days in a single string. However, it is repeating the day. Would it be possible to search for a particular value if it occurs twice within a string? I have gotten this far:

```
create table open_times (business_id int, open_day varchar(10), open_time varchar(10), close_day varchar(10), close_time varchar(10) )
insert into open_times (business_id, open_day, open_time, close_day, close_time) values (1, 'FRIDAY', '08:00', 'FRIDAY', '12:00')
insert into open_times (business_id, open_day, open_time, close_day, close_time) values (1, 'FRIDAY', '13:00', 'FRIDAY', '17:00')
insert into open_times (business_id, open_day, open_time, close_day, close_time) values (1, 'MONDAY', '08:00', 'MONDAY', '17:00')
insert into open_times (business_id, open_day, open_time, close_day, close_time) values (2, 'SATURDAY', '08:00', 'SATURDAY', '16:00')
insert into open_times (business_id, open_day, open_time, close_day, close_time) values (2, 'SUNDAY', '08:00', 'SUNDAY', '16:00')
insert into open_times (business_id, open_day, open_time, close_day, close_time) values (3, 'MONDAY', '08:00', 'MONDAY', '16:00')

drop table open_times
```

I appreciate your help.

```
    select 
    business_id
    ,left(name_values, LEN(name_values)-1) as opening_hours
from 
    (
    select 
            results.business_id
            ,STUFF((
                    select
                     ( case when open_day = 'FRIDAY' then 'Fr' when open_day = 'MONDAY' then 'Mo' when open_day = 'TUESDAY' then 'Tu' when open_day = 'WEDNESDAY' then 'We' When open_day = 'THURSDAY' then 'Th' when open_day = 'SATURDAY' then 'Sa' else 'Su' end )
                        + ' ' + open_time + '-' + close_time + '; '
                    from open_times
                    where business_id = results.business_id 
                    for xml path(''),type).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,0, '')  as name_values
            from open_times results
            group by business_id
    )  innerquery




Current Output for Business 1: 'Fr 08:00-12:00; Fr 13:00-17:00; Mo 08:00-17:00'   
Desired Output For Business 1: 'Fr 08:00-12:00, 13:00-17:00; Mo 08:00-17:00'
```

Comment: SQL is awful at this kind of stuff. Really you shouldn't be using delimited data in your data engine at all though.

Comment: Also, the name of the day, the opening time, and the closing time, should all be seperate items. The above should be a table, with 3 columns (`Day`, `OpeningTime`, `ClosingTime`) and 1 row for each opening time.

Comment: Why use SQL at all (which is terrible at text manipulation)? You're converting one string to another, not querying anything. If this is part of a query, you have a severe bug - storing multiple values in a single field. That breaks even the most basic design rule.

Comment: If those values were properly stored in a table, with one field for `Day`, one `time` field for `Open` and one for `Close` you could easily write a query that returned the Open/Close hours.

Comment: If for some reason you do need to store the data as a string, use JSON at least, so you can use the JSON functions to query the data.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server do you have `select @@version`

Comment: You have a column for the close day, which implies the day the store closes can be different to the one it opens. Is that true? You give no examples where that is the case.

Comment: This is a completely different question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with one level of aggregation by incorporating window functions into your logic:

```
select ot.business_id,
       stuff((select (case when seqnum = 1 then '; ' else ', ' end) +
                     (case when seqnum = 1 and ot2.open_day = 'FRIDAY' then 'Fr '
                           when seqnum = 1 and ot2.open_day = 'MONDAY' then 'Mo '
                           when seqnum = 1 and ot2.open_day = 'TUESDAY' then 'Tu '
                           when seqnum = 1 and ot2.open_day = 'WEDNESDAY' then 'We '
                           when seqnum = 1 and ot2.open_day = 'THURSDAY' then 'Th '
                           when seqnum = 1 and ot2.open_day = 'SATURDAY' then 'Sa '
                           when seqnum = 1 then 'Su '
                           else ''
                       end ) +
                    ot2.open_time + '-' + ot2.close_time 
              from (select ot2.*,
                           row_number() over (partition by ot2.open_day order by ot2.open_time) as seqnum
                    from open_times ot2
                    where ot2.business_id = ot.business_id 
                   ) ot2
              order by ot2.open_day, ot2.open_time
              for xml path(''),type
             ).value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ''
            )  as name_values
from open_times ot
group by ot.business_id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2976a9f944eb0cc990559bfb456b0b71) is a db<>fiddle.

Your version of the query is actually incorrect, because you do not have an `order by` in the XML subquery.  The results can be in any order.

In addition, you don't just want to remove the duplicate names, but you also want to change the delimiter from `;` to `,`.

The idea in the above query is that the times are enumerated on each day.  The delimiter is `;` for the first time and `,` for the subsequent ones.  The abbreviation is used only for the first one.  I also added qualifications to all the column references, a highly recommended practice.

Note that you can simplify the `case` logic to:

```
left(ot2.open_day, 1) + lower(substring(ot2.open_day, 2, 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `STRING_AGG` here. You just need to do two levels of grouping, once per day, then again for the whole `business_id`

```sql
SELECT
  ot.business_id,
  Times = STRING_AGG(CONCAT(
       UPPER(LEFT(ot.open_day, 1)),
       LOWER(SUBSTRING(ot.open_day, 2, 1)),
       ' ',
       ot.Times)
     , '; ')
FROM (
    SELECT
      ot.business_id,
      ot.open_day,
      Times = STRING_AGG(CONCAT(
        ot.open_time,
        '-',
        ot.close_time),
      ', ')
    FROM open_times ot
    GROUP BY ot.business_id, ot.open_day
) ot
GROUP BY ot.business_id;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8b25b49e61aa1cb9641b111730e577db)

Comment: I actually have 2016, sorry -- STR_AGG isn't a built in function

Answer (score 1):

For older versions use `FOR XML PATH` aggregation trick. Assuming no more then 2 open intervals a day

```
with t as (
  select business_id, left(open_day,2) +  ' ' + min(open_time + '-' + close_time) +
      case when min(open_time) = max(open_time) then '' 
          else ', ' + max(open_time + '-' + close_time) end ots
  from open_times
  group by business_id, open_day
)
select business_id, stuff( 
     (select '; ' + ots
      from t t2
      where t2.business_id = t1.business_id
      order by left(ots,2)
      for xml path(''))
     , 1, 2, '') opening_hours
from t t1
group by business_id
```